# Create spring boot restful Webservices without @EnableAutoconfig

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a Spring boot project which is packaged into jar and it functionalities are related to MQ and database. I want to now host a webservice on that project however I cannot use @EnableAutoConfiguration or @SpringBootApplication. The webservice to be created is a simple GET service that will return a integer value. I have tried following steps but still the webservice doesnt start.

1. Added Spring-webmvc, spring-web, spring-boot-web ,spring-tomcat jars to pom.xml
2. Changed the artifact type from jar to war in pom.xml
3. Added @EnableWebMvc in the config class
4. Added a class with @Controller and @RequestMapping
5. Created a bean for EmbeddedServletContext for Tomcat.

What have I missed?
 Some blogs mentioned about creating a WebApplicationContextInitializer and some mentioned about creating a Dispatcher servlet.

My question is what all beans do I need to manually create to bring up my webservice (as I cannot use EnableAutoConfig)

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?  I don't have any idea on an answer, but that information may help you get one from someone else.

Comment: Spring integration 4 (4.1.5)

Comment: Why can you not use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or `@SpringBootApplication`? It's not really a Spring Boot application if you don't use these. It sounds more like you want to create a regular Spring Web MVC application (not a Spring Boot application). Why are you trying to include Spring Boot?